# Bilinear Interpolation Negative Color Value

Tags: python, image, image-processing, interpolation, image-resizing

I wrote a code that apply an bilinear interpolation.I print my color values after interpolation, but there is an negative color values, float values and greater than 255.How do I fix this problem, please help me?

(I used 24 bit rgb image)

A part of color value printed :

```
[14 12 15]
[14 12 15]
[14 12 15]
[14 12 15]
[4010.54455662 4008.54455662 4011.54455662]
[3022.8009096 3020.8009096 3023.8009096]
[2035.05726258 2033.05726258 2036.05726258]
[1047.31361557 1045.31361557 1048.31361557]
[59.56996855 57.56996855 60.56996855]
[ 487.08683923   14.         -925.17367847]
[  980.95866274    14.         -1912.91732549]
[ 1474.83048625    14.         -2900.6609725 ]
[ 1968.70230976    14.         -3888.40461952]

for i in range(w * h):

    inp = np.dot(params_inverse, out) #Each output pixel multiplying transform params.
    k, j = inp[1][0], inp[2][0]

    if k < 0:
        k = 0

    if j < 0:
        j = 0

    if j >= h-1:
        j = h-1

    if k >= w-1:
        k = w-1

    neighbor = [m.floor(j), m.ceil(j), m.floor(k), m.ceil(k)]

    c1 = np.array(pixsel[neighbor[2], neighbor[0]])
    c2 = np.array(pixsel[neighbor[2], neighbor[1]]) - np.array(pixsel[neighbor[2], neighbor[0]])
    c3 = np.array(pixsel[neighbor[3], neighbor[0]]) - np.array(pixsel[neighbor[2], neighbor[0]])
    c4 = np.array(pixsel[neighbor[2], neighbor[0]]) - np.array(pixsel[neighbor[2], neighbor[1]]) - np.array(pixsel[neighbor[3], neighbor[0]]) + np.array(pixsel[neighbor[3], neighbor[1]])

    new_int = c1 + c2 * k * (1-j) + c3 * j * (1-k) + c4 * (k*j)

    print(new_int)
```

Comment: You must realize that we cannot see your screen, and therefore will never be able to help you unless you show what you’re doing. Consider adding a [mre] to your question.

Comment: `1-j` is a negative value if `j>0`. You are using absolute location where you should be using location relative to the 4 corners of the square formed by the 4 neighbors. The `j` and `k` in that line should be values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you for answer.There is something I do not understand. It refers to the j and k pixel coordinates, how can it be between 0 and 1. How can I fix this?

Comment: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation . Note the difference between `x`, `x1` and `x2` in those equations (the meanings are described in the figure). For your case, `x1=floor(x)` and `x2=ceil(x)`. Then the computations happen with `x-x1` and `x2-x` (note that `x2-x1` is expected to be 1). There's a problem here using `floor` and `ceil`, in that if `x` is integer, `x1` and `x2` are identical and their distance is 0. You can use `x2=floor(x+1)` to fix that issue.

Comment: I try it right now. Thank you very much @Cris Luengo

Comment: I did what he said. The values I received were positive, but they were floating. I used uint8 to fix this. Is this fix wrong?@Chris Luengo

Comment: It is normal that floating-point computations lead to floating-point values. You can round the interpolated values if you need the output to be uint8.